# How Draw circle on Zoom able and scroll able imageview android?

Tags: android, android-canvas, pinchzoom, touchimageview

I am developing an application and requirements are as below.

**Display image with pinch zoom and pan.**

For this I am using TouchImageview.java from [here](https://github.com/MikeOrtiz/TouchImageView)

And it is working as expected.

**Draw solid circle on Image.**

This is also working.

```
public class NavigationViewZoom extends TouchImageView {
    private Paint mPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);

    @Override
    public void setImageBitmap(Bitmap bm) {
        super.setImageBitmap(bm);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.drawCircle(300, 120, 50, mPaint);
    }

    public NavigationViewZoom(Context c) {
        super(c);
        init();
    }

    public NavigationViewZoom(Context c, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(c, attrs);
        setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {

        mPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

    }
}
```

**Problem:**

Now the problem is, when zoom in/out image after drawing solid circle on canvas the circle position is not managed.

**For Example** I draw solid circle on position x=100,y=100 after zooming the image the circle should be on same position. So how to get the relative x,y position on zoomed image.

Comment: some code will be appreciated..!!

Comment: create a class that extends `BitmapDrawable` and override its `draw` method

Comment: I am able to draw circle, but when zooming the image circle should not move.

Comment: if the circle should stay in a fixed position then just override `onDraw` method, if it should move see my comment above

Comment: @pskink My goal is display pointer on custom map. If you see in google map when we zoom map the pointer remains at same place it was before zoom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this [library](https://github.com/davemorrissey/subsampling-scale-image-view).
In demo app is shown a feature that seems to do what you want.

[CircleView](https://github.com/davemorrissey/subsampling-scale-image-view/wiki/10.-Extension) class in the library could be useful.